# Simulating Brownian motion in R. Is this correct?

Tags: r, probability, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes

I have a Weiner process $\{W(t)\}_{t\ge0}$ with $\sigma^2=\text{Var}(W(1))=1$. For a real constant $\epsilon>0$ consider the differential ratio process $\Delta_\epsilon=\{\Delta_\epsilon(t)\}_{r>0}$ given by
\begin{equation}
\Delta_\epsilon(t) = \frac{W(t+\epsilon)-W(t)}{\epsilon}, \quad \text{for} \ t>0.
\end{equation}

I want to simulate a sample path of $\{\Delta_\epsilon(t)\}_{t\in(0,1]}$ for small $\epsilon>0$ in Rstudio.

Simulating a basic Weinerprocess/Brownian motion is easy in R, one can do it by the function `rweiner()` or by plotting the cumulative sum of standard normally distributed variables. The part that confuses me is how to simulate the $W(t+\epsilon)$. What I've done is used [rwiener()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-3/topics/rwiener) and simply passed the `end` parameter to $1+\epsilon$.

```
epsilon = 10e-1
weinerEps = rwiener(end = 1+epsilon, frequency = 1000)
weiner = rwiener(end = 1, frequency = 1000)

Delta = (wienerEps - wiener)/epsilon

plot(Delta , type="l")
```

I'm not sure this is correct though. Anyone who knows how to properly do this?

Comment: The simulation is not correct. You should be using the fact that a Weiner process has $W(t+\varepsilon) - W(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\varepsilon)$. Also, if you are simulating $\Delta_{\varepsilon}$ paths on a grid, is the spacing between the points smaller or larger than $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Thanks! So I can essentially just simulate using normal distribution with variance $\epsilon$ and divide the result by $\epsilon$. However the plot is not what I expect it to be. If I make epsilon smaller, the amplitude of the time series should increase, but now it's rather constant. They are not simulated on the path of a grid.

Comment: Well, your original simulation is on a grid with spacing 1/1000. The Wiener increments are independent if they don't overlap; that's why I asked about how fine you want the grid to be. If the grid spacing is coarser than $\varepsilon$, a sampled path is iid normal, in which case you could simulate it directly easily, but otherwise it's probably easier to simulate a single Wiener path on the finest grid and take the differences appropriately (on a single path, not two independent paths like you have).

Comment: Indeed, I'm only interested in the part where they overlap, which occurs for $0\le t\le \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon\le t\le 0.$ However, I still don't get the result I expect. There is no difference in the plot regardless of how I change $\epsilon$. I've just done this: 

epsilon = 10e-10
Difference = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = epsilon)/epsilon
plot(Difference , type="l")

Comment: 1. $\varepsilon$ should be the variance, not the standard deviation like you've specified. If it's the standard deviation, then dividing by that same value gives you a standard normal so doesn't depend on the value of $\varepsilon$. 2. If you're only interested in the part where they overlap, then the iid normal simulation you have there is wrong.